# Can't access TextView from another method

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView block defined in a layout.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/article"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I define private attribute of a class as:

```
View inflatedView;
```

Later, in onCreateView method, it's given the value of:

```
inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

When accessing the TextView field from the onCreateView method, it makes no problem, however, trying to access it from other methods, returns null reference.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
TextView article = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.article);
```

I managed to get it to work by setting the article as private attribute, initializing it's value in onCreateView method, then using it in all other methods, however, I can't understand what's the problem with the approach above.

EDIT:

```
View inflatedView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }
    //article_view contains the article TextView
    inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    return inflatedView;
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

Comment: can you provide full code implementation of the first approach?

Comment: If the TextView is the root element in the layout, you don't need to call `findViewById(...)` - the call to `inflate(...)` will return the TextView directly.

Comment: and from where were you calling the updateArticleView() function?

Comment: @adelphus Can you explain it more thoroughly? What do I call inflate on?

Comment: @AhmadHammoud It's called from the MainActivity, that contains 2 fragments, one of them being the fragment with the methods described above.

Comment: @hazeiio in your code, you are already calling inflate() - just cast the resulting `inflatedView` variable to a `TextView`

Comment: @adelphus The suggested solution does indeed work, however, if I had more than 1 TextView in my layout, how to access each one of them?

Comment: @hazeiio each layout can only have *one* root element - if you have more than one TextView in a layout, then there must a parent layout containing them - in that case you must use `findViewById()` as you have done in your question. Simply put, `inflate()` returns the root view and `findViewById()` returns any descendant (child) views.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved the problem, by putting the TextView block inside the LinearLayout, and then calling the findViewById(R.id.article);

Managed to get the TextView both by using:

```
inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.article);
```

and

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that *inflatedView* is not null before using this method.

Comment: I checked it, the ".setText()" function is never called if it's null.

Comment: because it will cause an exception.